# Moderator Resignation

Tags: discussion

I just want to let you all know that I am resigning from my position as a Tor Stack Exchange Moderator, immediately. I've emailed the Community Team about this already and hopefully everything with go smoothly.

I want to give a special thanks to Jens Kubieziel and Alexey Vesnin for helping manage the site with me. I hope they continue to do so in the future and I wish them best of luck.

Thank you.

Comment: Godspeed in your future projects!

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin Thank you!